# Aussprache von Diphthongen beim Singen

Tags: pronunciation

Ich habe gelernt, beim Singen einen langgezogenen Vokal folgendermaßen auszusprechen:

`au` als `aaaaaaaaaa-o`

`ei` als `aaaaaaaaaa-e`

Ich weiß aber nicht, wie es bei einem `eu` zu handhaben ist.

Ist `Feuer` eher `Fooooooo-jer` oder etwas anderes?

Comment: Just listen: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxfWDLcsvPw ;-)

Comment: @splattne "Lief drei Minuten nur, doch nun rund um die Uhr lässt es dich nicht allein, was kann so grausam sein? so unverschämt perfid: Ein Lieed!" (Sebatian Krämer)

Comment: @splattne ist es absicht dass du dieses so nervtötende Lied in den Kommentar schreibst und damit deine Antwort vor der Bewertung des Liedes schützt? ^^;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Der Laut, der in die Länge gezogen werden muss, entspricht etwa dem Vokal, der im englischen Wort "call" enthalten ist.

```
Fɔː ... ier
```

Comment: Also ein sehr offenes O?

Comment: [ɔ: deutsch o („offenes“ o)](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lautzeichen#O). Gut erhören kann man es auch in [diesem Liedausschnitt](http://youtu.be/ANSkTespF_8?t=2m56s)